# Concatenate two list into a new list

Tags: list

I have two list:

```
lis1=[['a','b','x'],['c','d','x']]
lis2=['1','2']
```

and i wont a new list insert elements lis2 in lis like

```
[[['a','b','c','x'],['1']],
[['c','d','x'],['2']]]
```

What can i do?

Append method don't work for it.

Comment: You haven't specified your programming language and from your example it's really hard (wonder if possible) to understand *how* you want to concatenate your lists.

Comment: I think you have to provide more detail about the algorithm. I don't see why `'c'` suddenly appears in the first list of your result.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I use Python. Sorry